# My kivy app won't work in my phone(just a black scren), but works in my computer and with kivy launcher

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I'm learning kivy and after successfully using buildozer in a simple label app, I made a kivy app that is a little more complex with buttons, the strange thing is that this kivy app runs perfectly in my computer and with kivy launcher, but when I use buildozer to create and apk and install it in my phone the app doesn't do anything; when I launch the app the loading screen appears with the kivy logo, after that a black screen without anything. I'm not importing any library except from kivy, to test I made a really simple 1 button kivy app and the same happens.

-I'm only importing kivy in the the main.py, therefore I don't think that adding anything in the libraries to be imported by buildozer has anything to do with the problem.

-The logs don't show anything, the logs from an app that worked with a ping pong game and the app with buttons that doesn't work are exactly the same.

-The app doesn't crash just stays with a black screen so I think that something is not running properly in the apk, but it works in my computer and with the kivy launcher in my phone, that is why I believe that probably is some configuration in the creation of the app with buildozer that makes the app behave strange in the phone.

-The only difference with the other apps that worked are the buttons, maybe something makes the app to not work properly because of the buttons?, but it would be strange that more complex things like an animation works but buttons do not.
If anyone has any idea I would appreciate the help.

main.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class ButtonTest(FloatLayout):
  pass

class BtnTestApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return ButtonTest()

if __name__=='__main__':
  BtnTestApp().run()
```

BtnTest.kv file:

```
<ButtonTest>:
  Button:
    text:'A'
    on_press: self.text= self.text + 'A'
```

The buildozer file:

[app]

```
# (str) Title of your application
title = Test 5

# (str) Package name
package.name = test5

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = 

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
#android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to stable
#p4a.branch = stable

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

adb logcat:

```
I/python  ( 9427): Initialize Python for Android
I/python  ( 9427): Changing directory to the one provided by ANDROID_ARGUMENT
I/python  ( 9427): /data/data/org.test.test5/files/app
I/python  ( 9427): Preparing to initialize python
I/python  ( 9427): crystax_python does not exist
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1560): setHidden false
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1560): setHidden false
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1560): setHidden false
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1560): setHidden false
D/BatteryStatsImpl( 1560): ++++++xy WakeLock stop : pid=1560, name=, type=0, tid=2389, pid=1560, pName=null
I/ActivityManager( 1560): Process com.wssnps (pid 9263) (adj 10) has died.
D/BRCM_EGL( 9427): eglMakeCurrent(0x450d3978, 0x47c24868, 0x47c24868) Thread: 9427
D/BRCM_EGL( 9427): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 9427
D/BRCM_EGL( 1659): eglMakeCurrent(0x40edd980, 0x47c35680, 0x47c35680) Thread: 1659
D/BRCM_EGL( 1659): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 1659
I/python  ( 9427): Initialized python
I/python  ( 9427): AND: Init threads
I/python  ( 9427): testing python print redirection
I/python  ( 9427): Setting up python from ANDROID_PRIVATE
I/python  ( 9427): ('Android path', ['/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app/lib/python27.zip', '/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app/lib/python2.7/', '/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/', '/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/', '/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app'])
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1560): setHidden false
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1218): id=761 Removed idx=4 Map Size=5
I/SurfaceFlinger( 1218): id=761 Removed idx=-2 Map Size=5
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1560): setHidden false
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1560): setHidden false
I/python  ( 9427): ('os.environ is', {'ANDROID_APP_PATH': '/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app', 'EXTERNAL_STORAGE': '/storage/sdcard0', 'LOOP_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/obb', 'ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote': '9', 'BOOTCLASSPATH': '/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework2.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/sec_edm.jar:/system/framework/seccamera.jar', 'ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE': '8,66560', 'PATH': '/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/vendor/lib:/system/lib', 'ANDROID_ASSETS': '/system/app', 'ANDROID_BOOTLOGO': '1', 'PYTHONOPTIMIZE': '2', 'ANDROID_PRIVATE': '/data/data/org.test.test5/files', 'ANDROID_ENTRYPOINT': 'main.pyo', 'SECONDARY_STORAGE': '/storage/extSdCard:/storage/UsbDriveA:/storage/UsbDriveB:/storage/UsbDriveC:/storage/UsbDriveD:/storage/UsbDriveE:/storage/UsbDriveF', 'PYTHONPATH': '/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app:/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app/lib', 'ANDROID_DATA': '/data', 'PYTHON_NAME': 'python', 'ANDROID_ROOT': '/system', 'PYTHONHOME': '/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app', 'ASEC_MOUNTPOINT': '/mnt/asec', 'ANDROID_UNPACK': '/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app', 'ANDROID_ARGUMENT': '/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app'})
I/python  ( 9427): ('Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is', '__main__')
D/Launcher.HomeFragment(16347): onStop
D/Launcher(16347): onStop, Launcher: 1098854560
D/BRCM_EGL(16347): eglMakeCurrent(0x4694d780, 0x40e3b208, 0x40e3b208) Thread: 16347
D/BRCM_EGL(16347): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 16347
D/BRCM_EGL(16347): eglMakeCurrent(0x4694d780, 0x40e3b208, 0x40e3b208) Thread: 16347
D/Launcher(16347): onTrimMemory. Level: 80
D/Launcher(16347): releaseShadows called
I/python  ( 9427): ['/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/data/org.test.test5/files/app/lib/site-python']
I/python  ( 9427): AND: Ran string
I/python  ( 9427): Run user program, change dir and execute entrypoint
D/BRCM_EGL(16347): eglMakeCurrent(NULL) Thread: 16347
W/ManagedEGLContext(16347): doTerminate failed: EGL count is 2 but managed count is 1
I/System.out( 1560): changing priority of pid :16347 to -8
I/ActivityManager( 1560): Process com.sec.android.app.clockpackage (pid 9359) (adj 9) has died.
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/data/org.test.test5/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-04-28_0.txt
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, Apr 27 2018, 18:02:08) 
I/python  ( 9427): [GCC 4.8]
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
D/BRCM_EGL( 1659): eglMakeCurrent(0x40edd980, 0x4b7ed8d8, 0x4b7ed8d8) Thread: 1659
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1560): setHidden false
D/PowerManagerService( 1560): acquireWakeLock flags=0x2000000a tag=KEEP_SCREEN_ON_FLAG uid=1000 pid=1560
D/BRCM_EGL( 9427): eglCreateWindowSurface() surface: 0x4ed58fb0, VC surface: 4, Thread: 9453
D/BRCM_EGL( 9427): eglCreateContext() config: 25 context: 0x4ba2e668, VC context 2, Thread 9453
D/BRCM_EGL( 9427): eglMakeCurrent(0x4ba2e668, 0x4ed58fb0, 0x4ed58fb0) Thread: 9453
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1560): setHidden false
D/PowerManagerService( 1560): releaseWakeLockLocked : ON_AFTER_RELEASE
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 2.0>
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Broadcom>
D/PowerManagerService( 1560): releaseWakeLockLocked flags=0x0 tag=KEEP_SCREEN_ON_FLAG
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <VideoCore IV HW>
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <2048>
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <8>
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <Compiled>
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <Compiled>
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
I/python  ( 9427): [WARNING] [Base        ] Unknown <android> provider
I/python  ( 9427): [INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
I/python  ( 9427): [ERROR  ] [Base        ] Failed to import "android" module. Could not remove android presplash.
I/ActivityManager( 1560): Process eu.chainfire.supersu (pid 9398) (adj 9) has died.
```

Comment: what is your **kv** file name? It must be **btntest** and in the same directory of your **main** file

Comment: Post the full adb logcat log.

Comment: Good day, I added the logcat and the name of the kv file is BtnTest.kv.

Comment: change it to **btntest** and it should be in the same directory of your **main.py**

Comment: If you don't want to change it, you can load it in your **main** file with **builder.load_file('BtnTest.kv')**

Comment: Thank you very much that solved the black screen, I changed the kv file to lowercase and it worked, I never thought of that.

Comment: you are welcome